# Is there a list showing the last time each country had a peaceful transition of government?

Tags: democracy

According to a paper on the [definition of democracy](https://muse.jhu.edu/article/48095):

> The simplest definition of democracy has been given by Karl Popper: a system that makes it possible to get rid of a government without spilling blood. This definition may be a little too restrictive, and perhaps it is laconic rather than simple. Its implications, in fact, are really rather complex.

Is there a list that shows the last time each country had a peaceful transition of government? E.g. for the US that date would be November 2016, while for Russia it would be sometime in 1991.

Comment: Related: https://politics.stackexchange.com/questions/102/what-are-the-minimum-requirements-for-a-system-to-be-called-democratic

Comment: "Get rid of a government" seems a little vague.  It seems the US has had the same government since about 1788.  Not that I'm complaining.  Whether we could replace our current system of government without spilling blood remains to be seen.

Comment: @James: note that "government" is sometimes used as a synonym of "administration" or "decision makers" or "executives", especially outside of AmEnglish. In a Westminster-style parliament the executive is part of the legislature, so a leader being voted out of office is not necessary for a transfer of power to take place. The American Executive changed in November 2016, the Legislature has a slight turnover (~10-15% of House elections defeat an incumbent and a higher percentage of Senate elections) on a biannual basis, and the judiciary is appointed.

Comment: @James the American President (who is the most powerful person in the US government) changes every 4-8 years without a break and is often opposed by his predecessor. In contrast, the Russian Presidency has been perfectly stable since 1991.

Comment: The World Almanac lists this information on a country by country basis in each year's edition as part of the information about that country in a digest of key information about each country on Earth. It is trivial although time consuming to turn that data into a chart.

Comment: @ohwilleke does World Almanac lists Russia as last having a change of government in 1991?

Comment: @JonathanReez The most recent edition (2018) notes the transition from the Soviet Union to the Russian Federation in 1991 and recounts in detail every significant political event in the Russia Federation since its inception.

Comment: I don't get the reference to 1991.  Ignoring the period 2008-2012 (during which Putin retained many of the powers of president without holding the title) the last time the Presidency in Russia changed was in 1999, when Yeltin resigned.  I'd assume this was a typo, but it has been repeated in comments. Please clarify

Comment: @JamesK the President did change in 1999, but it wasn't a transition of government as Putin was Yeltsin's chosen successor. He was nominated as Acting President on December 31st 1999 by Yeltsin and stayed in power ever since. Same applies to many semi-totalitarian states.

Comment: I don't think this can be objectively answered. Consider the UK.  When was the last peaceful transition?  Brown->Cameron/Clegg coalition in 2010?  Coalition->Conservative (but keeping same PM) in 2015? Cameron->May (without a general election) in 2016? The last General election (which resulted in a minority government) in 2017?  Or, since the UK has a cabinet govnerment, was it the last time the cabinet changed? Or was it 1688 and the Glorious Revolution?

Comment: @JamesK it would be 2016 since David Cameron didn't choose May to be his successor, she was first elected by the Conservative party and then reelected in a fair public election in 2017. It's only subjective for countries which are somewhere between democracy and authoritarianism.

Comment: There seems to be a major problem with defining democracy as transition without spilling blood, because by that definition, North Korea has been a democracy since 1948.

Comment: @jamesqf there has been no transition of power in North Korea. Kim senior handing over the reigns to Kin junior doesn't count.

Comment: @JonathanReez: Why doesn't it count?  How is it different than a US President handing over power to the next one?  Especially if they happen to be of the same party.

Comment: @jamesqf because the election ballot in North Korea doesn't even offer other candidates, unlike US primaries and elections.

Comment: But the problem as I see it is that I would have not called the change from Cameron to May as a transition of government. It was merely a change of PM, and it wasn't done "democratically". I would have called the Brown->Coalition the last proper change of government.  So you will need to define what counts for every country. And when you've done that you will have your answer - but it won't be very useful as it will change the next time some government changes. And it will only be for you, as other people will have a different understanding of what is a transition.

Comment: @JonathanReez Based on the comments I see; this question will need to first define what you mean by "government" and secondly what you would define as a "peaceful transition". Caveats like "chosen successor" or "doesn't even offer other candidates" are critical to getting this question answered. Finally, what list of countries do you want? All through all time? Only the countries that currently exist? How would the eligible countries be defined? Would elected nepotism count? There are a lot of considerations left open for interpretation here.